# Is there a way to add easing to Scrollorama?

Tags: jquery, easing

Is there a way to add easing to the following Scrollorama effect so it doesn't jerk up and down the screen?

Thanks

```
            $().ready(function() {
                var scrollorama = $.scrollorama({ blocks:'#wrapper' });
            scrollorama.animate('.work_dots',{ delay: 200, duration: 1100, property:'top', start:-700, end:100 });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It has an `easing` property which can be added to the config object passed to `.animate()`